# How does the model structure look like for Kendo TreeView, to bind remote data?

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, treeview

How does the model structure look like for Kendo TreeView, to bind remote data

Answer (score 0):

We have a tree displaying system locations which have hierarchical structure. We use the following code:
C# code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetChildrenAsync(long? parentId)
    {
        //retrieving location's children by parentId
        //DTO has ChildrenCount field that shows how many children has any particular location

        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = locations.Select(x => new
            {
                LocationId = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                HasChildren = x.ChildrenCount > 0
            }),
            MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
        };
    }
```

JS code:

```
var locationDataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            type: "json",
            read: {
                url: "@Url.Action("GetChildren", "Location")",
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data) {
                return { parentId: data.LocationId };
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "LocationId",
                hasChildren: "HasChildren"
            }
        }
    });

    var kendoTree = $("#location-tree").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: locationDataSource,
        dataTextField: "Name"
    });
```